Has technology regressed in the Alien universe?
From Alien: Prometheus (2012) and Alien: Covenant (2017), we have seen human technology have become very advanced. 
A few examples are ship deck interiors, computers, interfaces such as monitors and cryo chambers. 
But, over time, with the story progresses, we notice there is a regression in technology.
In a chronological order, we have
Ship control panel from Prometheus (2012)

Hologram map from Prometheus (2012)

Camera footage from Prometheus (2012)

Cryo chamber from Prometheus (2012)

Hologram map from Covenant (2017)

Control from Covenant (2017)

Cryo chamber from Alien (1979)

Interface from Alien (1979)

Control from Alien (1979)

In the latest Alien: Romulus (2024), their technology is on par with these from Alien: analog screen, big industrial buttons, etc.
Is there is an in-universe explanation regarding this technology regression?

I've never understood the out-of-universe desire to update fictional tech with those ridiculous CGI displays. I recall the showrunner for Star Trek: Discovery saying that audiences "expected it", but then his show was a ratings flop, so what does he know?

Yes, it really breaks the illusion of there being a fictional universe with its own consistent technology. The Star Wars prequels really messed that up, too.

Really annoyed me no end too. Its ridiculous but they never listen. Fede is doing a bit of a fan service, but in doing so its nice to see the tech back, though its obviously not for my generation anymore...

Who says it's a regression? Maybe one of our great achievements was figuring out how to replace those crappy, overcomplicated touchscreens with luxurious, intuitive control panels with real buttons and knobs.

'Who says it's a regression?' - Amen.

The latest film takes place chronologically between the first two films. https://time.com/7010555/alien-romulus-franchise-timeline/

The point would be clearer if you tagged the images with in-world dates as well

After a Deadly Collision, the Navy Is Ditching Complex Digital Warship Controls: Overly complicated control systems were cited as a factor in the 2017 collision between the destroyer USS McCain and a civilian tanker.

It’s not directly addressed in the films. The real-life reason is obvious, but there is a plausible in-universe interpretation:

The Prometheus mission was run by Peter Weyland himself. He was incredibly rich, and had access to state-of-the-art equipment.

The Covenant was a colonisation ship, designed to sustain human life for decades. There were thousands of embryos on board. It was worth spending the money to fill this ship with the best equipment.

The Nostromo was an industrial refinery vessel with a tiny crew, who are (per Mother’s instructions) “expendable”. The scriptwriters referred to them as “truckers in space”. No point sending one of your good ships on that mission.

The Sulaco was a military vessel, and so needed to be durable and functional, rather than aesthetically appealing.


Yes, it would be better if the directors and production designers had actually tried to achieve some consistency, but there is at least some attempt to address this in Alien: Romulus (2024), which adopts a similar aesthetic to the original movie.

There's a great detail about the cryo pods' technology: In Prometheus (and possibly Covenant), the whole crew is sick when they get out of cryo, whereas in Alien, which takes place later than the others, they wake up as if from a good night's sleep. This suggests cryo technology improved over time.
Also, there's the contrast between the "industrial mining ship" in Alien and the "personal habitat with an operating robot because I'm Peter Weyland" in Prometheus. The first being utilitarian and the latter being state-of-the-art.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

bad bot! Just because it's my first comment doesn't mean it's unclear
